# How to retrieve _id field from document containing both _id and id

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I'm trying to query a mongodb collection with documents containing both an `_id` and and `id` field (I know this is not an ideal db design, but I don't own the db).

Is there a way to access the `_id` field using MongoEngine in Flask?

`doc['id']` returns the `id` field and `doc['_id']` throws a KeyError.